# From CTRL+"something" to a string with a code sample

Tags: c#

```
    public virtual void Send(string keysToType, ActionListener actionListener)
    {
        if (heldKeys.Count > 0) keysToType = keysToType.ToLower();

        CapsLockOn = false;
        foreach (char c in keysToType)
        {
            short key = VkKeyScan(c);
            if (c.Equals('\r')) continue;

            if (ShiftKeyIsNeeded(key)) SendKeyDown((short) KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT, false);
            if (CtrlKeyIsNeeded(key)) SendKeyDown((short) KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL, false);
            if (AltKeyIsNeeded(key)) SendKeyDown((short) KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.ALT, false);
            Press(key, false);
            if (ShiftKeyIsNeeded(key)) SendKeyUp((short) KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT, false);
            if (CtrlKeyIsNeeded(key)) SendKeyUp((short) KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL, false);
            if (AltKeyIsNeeded(key)) SendKeyUp((short) KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.ALT, false);
        }

        actionListener.ActionPerformed(Action.WindowMessage);
    }
```

I need to send a list of keyboard shortcuts to that method

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, etc.

But I don't know how to build such a string.

This far I wrote this:

```
 string shortcuts;
 // shortcuts = "\CTRL + A" + "\CTRL + End";
 Send(shortcuts, myactionlistener)
```

Comment: You should try to add this information to your existing question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a 'normal' string is not the best format to do this?

If the string contains 'characters that need to be sent', perhaps a list of `KeyEventArgs` or some custom built data class could be sent to your Send method. Then you can loop over the list and execute one by one. If you need combinations (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (=toggle bookmark in Visual Studio)) you might need a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Another option is to create your own [DSL](http://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html).

Comment: The problem is I didn't write the "Send" code, I'm actually using the TestStack.White framework. So, unless the authors change the way it works, I'll have to comply with the String use.

Comment: Use a tool like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to see how they implemented the methods `CtrlKeyIsNeeded`, etc. There you can see what they expect in the input string as 'press Ctrl'.

Comment: Since the method itself "parse" each string's characters with VkKeyScan (user32.dll), I don't see how I could "trick" the parsing. I'm not really familiar with VkKeyScan, though and some key combination seems to just not exist (CTRL+END) as single character.

Comment: The way the Send function is implemented it only allows single characters to be send. Hence why it wouldn't be possible to send a CTRL+END as it has no meaning on the keyboard. Basically this implementation is wrong on many levels. I would demand your developer to provide a better implementation of Send, (allowing an ordered list of combination for example.)

Comment: You're right. But I found a set of methods in the framework that allow to keep any key held and release them later. Too bad all the example I had read were somewhat misleading since they didn't use any of those.

Answer (score 1):

Too late for Serge but for all the googlers out there...

Serge is referring to the [Keyboard](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/InputDevices/Keyboard.cs) class in TestStack.White. The `Send` function can only be used to send strings literally to another window. You cannot specify control keys here. They are just needed internally sometimes. E.g. `Send("{")` on my keyboard layout would internally translate to "AltKeyIsNeeded" and "7".

You can send keyboard shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> like this:

```
myWindow.Keyboard.HoldKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL);
myWindow.Keyboard.Enter("A");
myWindow.Keyboard.LeaveKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL);

myWindow.Keyboard.HoldKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL);
myWindow.Keyboard.HoldKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.END);
myWindow.Keyboard.LeaveKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.END);
myWindow.Keyboard.LeaveKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in an application, with the Windows key' shortcuts. I'm used a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook` and when I've got a specific shortcut I call the method. Maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience of UI automation there were some cases where solution of @m3tikn0b didn't work for me, particularly ALT+DOWN and ALT+UP, not sure why. To make them work I had to use WinForm's SendKeys, for example for ALT+DOWN it is:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%({DOWN})");
```

It has pretty rich syntax described in [docs for Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.8) method. However it was not suitable in all my cases as well, so I had to use TestStack.White for the most cases and SendKeys for some rare exclusions.